# cc: unrecognized option '-KPIC'

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile

I have the following in my makefile:

```
CC = cc -g -KPIC
```

When I run the makefile, I get the following error.

```
cc -g -KPIC   -DORA817 -DIDA_VERSION='"ISP-RG-V5.10.7GEN2A"' -c -g  -DDEBUG -DDEBUGLEVEL=0  -I../include -I../../../include -c \
        -o ../obj/checkdate.o ../src/checkdate.c
cc: unrecognized option '-KPIC'
```

The version of my gcc is gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44).
Any idea why this error occurs?

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs, just as the compiler says, because `-KPIC` is not a valid option.

Perhaps you meant `-fPIC`?